# How can I plot this graph in R?

Tags: r, regression, cart

I'm reading "An Introduction to Statistical Learning" and noticed the following plot made in the book for a regression tree:

[image]

I'm trying to make a similar plot for my [dataset](http://zangsir.weebly.com/uploads/3/1/3/8/3138983/wine2.arff) but can't figure out how to make it in R. The book doesn't provide the R-code used to plot the data as shown in the image.

If someone can show me how to do it just for Training, I can replicate it for CV and Test.

Or if someone can show how to build a graph like this from example data points I can take it from there

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about coding.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm trying to reproduce the exact same graph.

Answer (score 0):

This website seems to show the steps needed to get the graph you want (assuming you're not opposed to using ggplot2):

http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/

If you want the white background instead of the gray one, you can play around with using theme command with ggplot.

Note: You may have to convert your data to a dataframe and make sure it's in "long" format as opposed to "wide" format. This is a requirement of ggplot2.